# php tmpfile() - Could not create temporary files

Tags: php, macos, tmp

I'm using Mac OSX, and when I try to create a temporary file, I get this message:

```
$temp_file  =  tmpfile();
```

> Could not create temporary files for attachments. Your tmp directory
>   may be unwritable by PHP

I checked the directory, and here's what I see:

```
echo sys_get_temp_dir();

ls -ld /var/folders/v1/9BmtDyVv7v15d6qx07_4ylfh0000gn/T
drwx------  41 mark  staff  1394 Feb 21 12:44 /var/folders/v1/9BmtDyVv7v15d6qx07_4ylfh0000gn/T
```

Comment: you dont have write permissions set for the directory `drwx------`, only the user `mark` does

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the error message in combination with the output should be more enough to help you help yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're mark ?

```
<?php var_dump(get_current_user()); // will probably display www-data
```

If, as I guess you are, you're executing this script with a web-server, keep in mind the web server is probably run by another user than you (which is a security best practice), even if the startup script is run by root.

Comment: It's showing `mark`. And when I change the permissions to 777, it works.